# how to do subtraction in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

i want to subtract 1 from a variable who is stored in my table in mysql

i do it by this query

```
UPDATE table SET  var = var -1
```

but when i do it

```
0 - 1 = -1
```

but mysql do

`0 - 1 = 9223372036854775807` when i set in bigint
when i set it to int property then he do

```
0 -1 = 2147483647
```

what i do to get

```
0 - 1 = -1
```

Comment: Can you show the whole sql statement?

Comment: Is the data type signed or unsigned? And was the value 0 before?

Comment: We need to see the table definition to answer that!

Comment: @Richa: Why again? You have already got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807769/minus-value-in-mysql-table-not-worked

Comment: @Veer: yeah he already got answers there, i suggested he use BIGINT.  then he deleted his question.  now he is asking for BIGINT scenario, but i refuse to answer now, I don't know anything bigger than BIGINT (at least with whole number type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose a different (signed) data type that allows storing negative values.

look here for some background :

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html
- [Signed versus Unsigned Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247873/signed-versus-unsigned-integers)