# Can int range swith to 2 - 4 billions

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee

Normally Java int has range -2147483648...2147483647, so the max value is 2147483647, I don't want to use negative number. an int can have more than 4 billions of different values, can I use int range 2-4 billions? in eclipse, I use int a = 31474836471; I get compile error. how do I do?

Comment: Use a long type variable.

Comment: [Java doesn't support unsigned ints](http://stackoverflow.com/q/430346/851811). Use `long` instead.

Comment: You could always store the wanted value **-2147483648** and add it again when interpreting the value. Disadvantage: arithmetic operations will no longer be valid.

Answer (score 4):

You've already asked this Question as part of another one.

The Answer is no, you cannot make the Java `int` type so that you have 4 billion values >= zero.

And asking the same Question again won't change the Answer.

You need to change your program to replace the "pk" type from `int` to `long`.  You have no other alternatives, given you have stated that keys must be >= zero.

Answer (score 2):

No, in Java, all numbers are signed; there are no unsigned numbers.  If you need a higher range of integers, then use [`long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: Can you switch on a long? EDIT Just found out that you can't.

Comment: Apparently, you can't use `switch` on a `long`, but that wasn't part of your original question.  Why would you need to switch on a long?  Do you really have billions of cases?

Comment: `char` is the only unsigned number type in java `0..65535`

Comment: @SoulDZIN Can't you just try it?

Comment: @DaveNewton - better still, he could look it up in the JLS.

Comment: @StephenC Oh you. The JLS is hard, let's go stackoverflowing.

Comment: @Dave Newton I asked because I was too lazy to create a new project just to test it out. But that's what I ended up doing anyways and as I expected, you can't switch a long (which is weird since with the new java you can switch a string...)

Comment: @SoulDZIN you wouldn't need a new project, just a long, and a file with a main method. Should take all of a couple of minutes.

Comment: Just realized that this question wasn't asking about int and 'switch' statements, I misread the title. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The negative range is available for `int`s because the value is signed.  Only so much information can be represented in the bits.

See this other question for some good differentiation between signed and unsigned numbers: [Signed versus Unsigned Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247873/signed-versus-unsigned-integers)