# conversion of unsigned integer variable to signed variable

Tags: c, unsigned, signed

why does below program gives the output that **b** is greater than **a**?
Even though **b** contains -2.

```
void main()
{
    unsigned int a=12;
    int b=-2;

    if(a>b)
        printf("a is greater");
    else
        printf("b is greater");

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Why do you not expect 12 > -2?

Comment: Um, math agrees with your results.

Comment: Take a look on [Usual Arithmetic Conversion](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm)

Comment: The conversion goes the opposite way: signed -> unsigned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Signed versus Unsigned Integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247873/signed-versus-unsigned-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform the comparison, both operands are first converted to the same type.  In this case, `int b` is converted to the higher ranking `unsigned`.  For the comparison values, it is then `12 > (-2 + (UINTMAX + 1))`? which is false.

To compare in the usual mathematical sense:

```
unsigned int a;
int b;

if ((b < 0) || (a > b)) printf("a is greater");
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to quote the `C11` standard for relational operators, chapter 6.5.8

> If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are
>   performed.

Now, following the description in chapter 6.3.1.8, *Usual arithmetic conversions*, if you try to perform arithmetic operation between a `signed` and an `unsigned` integer (type), the `signed` one will get promoted to `unsigned` type (higher rank) and then the operation will take place.

So, here, for the comparison, the value of `b` is getting converted to `unsigned` type and you're getting the *wrong* output there.

To quote the relevant part, from the same chapter

> [...] Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

You can also check on the usual arithmetic promotion rule [here](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html)

That said, `void main()` should be `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, or, at least, `int main(void)`.

Comment: Comparing is not an arithmetic operation.

Comment: @Alex.S `If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are
performed.`

Comment: @Alex.S How is comparing not an arithmetic operation?

Comment: @chux Because comparison is not an arithmetic operation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic

Comment: @Alex.S At the risk of a [duck/rabbit season](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-k5J4RxQdE) exchange, a comparison like `a>b` is done by subtraction which is certain arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the type promotion rules: if one argument is an `int` and the other an `unsigned int` then the `int` is promoted to an `unsigned int`, adding UINT_MAX + 1 if necessary.

This happens prior to the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(a>b)
```

In this `a` is `unsigned int`  and `b` is `signed int` , so due to implicit conversion , `b` will be converted to `unsigned int type` and `b` will have a large value (no need to say, it will be greater than `a`).

Therefore ,you get unexpected result.

> According to C99- 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions
>
> [...]
>
> 3.Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.