# How to create a negative binary number using signed/unsigned in C?

Tags: c, int

My thoughts: if one declares an `int` it basically gets an `unsigned int`. So if I need a negative value I have to explicitly create a signed int.

I tried

```
int a = 0b10000101;
printf("%d", a); // i get 138 ,what i've expected
signed int b = 0b10000101; // here i expect -10, but i also get 138
printf("%d", b); // also tried %u
```

So am I wrong that an signed integer in binary is a negative value?
How can I create a negative value in binary format?

**Edit** Even if I use 16/32/64 bits I get the same result. `unsigned/signed` doest seems to make a difference without manually shifting the bits.

Comment: `int` ***is*** always `signed`, so there's no difference between `a` and `b` in your example. The most common way to represent signed integer types is *two's complement*, so please [read more about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: -10 in 2's complement is `leading ones... 11110110`.  why do you expect `0b10000101` to be -10?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that, depending on your target, `int` could be 2 or 4 bytes.  This means that `int a=0b10000101` is not nearly enough bits to set the sign bit.

If your `int` is 4 bytes, you need `0b10000000 0000000 0000000 00000000` (spaces added for clarity).

For example on a 32-bit target:

```
int b = 0b11111111111111111111111111111110; 
printf("%d\n", b);   // prints -2
```

Comment: See my updated example, make sure you have the right number of bits.  Double count if necessary, it's easy to be off.

Comment: Oh ok i thought i dont have to do the binary operation (flip the bits) if i declare signed or unsigned? So why to use it?

Comment: `int` is by default `signed`,  you really only need to specify `unsigned`.  also keep in mind that to print unsigned you need to use `%u`.

Comment: If you say "its signed by default" does it mean its "negative" by default?

Comment: @StrangerThings it means that values can be negative or positive, unsigned means you only have positive numbers.

Comment: No, signed doesn't mean negative.  Read more about [signed vs unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247873/signed-versus-unsigned-integers)

Answer (score 1):

because `int a = 0b10000101` has only 8 bits, where you need 16 or 32. Try thi:

```
int a = 0b10000000000000000000000000000101
```

that should create negative number if your machine is 32bits. If this does not work try:

```
int a = 0b1000000000000101
```

there are other ways to produce negative numbers:

```
int a = 0b1 << 31 + 0b101
```

or if you have 16 bit system

```
int a = 0b1 << 15 + 0b101
```

or this one would work for both 32 or 16 bits

```
int a = ~0b0 * 0b101
```

or this is another one that would work on both if you want to get -5

```
int a = ~0b101 + 1
```

so `0b101` is `5` in binary, `~0b101` gives `-6` so to get `-5` you add `1`

EDIT:
Since I now see that you have confusion of what signed and unsigned numbers are, I will try to explain it as simple as possible `int`

So when you have:

```
 int a = 5;
```

is the same as:

```
 signed int a = 5;
```

and both of them would be positive. Now it would be the same as:

```
 unsigned int a = 5;
```

because `5` is positive number.

On the other hand if you have:

```
int a = -5;
```

this would be the same as

```
signed int a = -5;
```

but it would not be the same as following:

```
unsigned int a = -5;
```

the first `2` would be `-5`, the third one is not the same. In fact it would be the same if you entered `4294967291` because they are the same in binary form but the fact that you have unsigned in front means that compiler would store it the same way but treat it as positive value.

Comment: It doesnt work but ODYN-Kon's answer worked for me. But i expected the same like you.. Of course bit shifting works as expected but i asked about signed/unsigned usage.

Comment: Your first four examples all involve undefined behavior as far as the C language is concerned.  Also, C specifies the effect of assigning a negative value to an unsigned integer in a way that does not depend on representation.  The result will *not* have the same representation on a sign/magnitude or one's complement machine -- both of which C explicitly allows -- not that you're likely to actually run into such a machine.

Comment: @JohnBollinger so I got the second part and you are right. I completely forgot about that one. But why undefined behavior? the other thing is that I tent to simplify sometimes things for those who are beginners.

Comment: @Gox, constants are positive.  Assigning a large positive constant to a signed integer so as to cause overflow produces undefined behavior.  Similarly, a left shift of a signed integer (including a signed integer constant) whose mathematical result is out of range for the type also produces undefined behavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for your input. I did find out what you are saying. I can say I learned a bit here.

Answer (score 1):

If numbers are represented as two's complement you just need to have the sign bit set to ensure that the number is negative. That's the MSB. If an `int` is 32 bits, then `0b11111111111111111111111111111111` is `-1`, and `0b10000000000000000000000000000000` is `INT_MIN`.

To adjust for the size `int(8|16|64)_t`, just change the number of bits.  The sign bit is still the MSB.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a negative binary number using signed/unsigned in C?

Simply negate the constant of a positive value.  To attempt to do so with `many 1's 
 ... 1110110` assumes a bit width for `int`.  Better to be portable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  #define NEGATIVE_BINARY_NUMBER (-0b1010)
  printf("%d\n", NEGATIVE_BINARY_NUMBER);
}
```

Output

```
-10
```

Comment: what does this have to do with signed/unsigned statement?

Comment: @StrangerThings `0b1010` is an integer constant of type `signed int`.  The assignment to an `int` variable like `signed int b = some_value` is not necessary to achieve "How to create a negative binary number".  `-0b1010` itself is a "negative binary number".