# i & 0xFF vs i % 256 with negative numbers

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, modulo, bitwise-and

I am wondering why (i % 256) and (i & 0xFF) is the same if i is 0 or positive, but completely different if i is negative.

Code used to Test:

```js
i = -100
while (i < 100) {
    if (!((i & 0xFF) == (i % 256))) console.log(i);
    i++;
}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative numbers are represented in the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) form, that is, the binary representation of `-100` is

```
(2**32 - 100).toString(2) = 11111111111111111111111110011100
```

adding `0xff` gives `10011100`, which is `156`.

The modulus operation `%` is defined as

```
IF a % b == r  THEN a == b * q + r for some q
```

There are always two choices for `q` and `r`, with a positive and a negative remainder. For example, with `7 % 3`,

```
 7 = 3 * 2 + 1
 7 = 3 * 3 - 2
```

The same for negative numbers, `-7 % 3`:

```
 -7 = 3 * (-2) - 1
 -7 = 3 * (-3) + 2
```

For positive numbers, all languages pick the positive remainder. For negative numbers, the choice is different from language to language. e.g. in python, the remainder is always positive, so

```
 -7 % 3 = 2   # python
```

Javascript picks the negative remainder, so in JS

```
 -7 % 3 = -1  // javascript
```

Similarly, for `-100 % 256`

```
-100 = 256 * ( 0) - 100
-100 = 256 * (-1) + 156
```

In python the remainder would be `156` (and thus match the `& FF`), in javascript it's `-100`.

Answer (score 1):

### First a summary of the operators:

`&` is the bitwise and operator.

- E.g., for a positive 4-bit number,

```
0110 (6)
0100 (4) &
-------
0100 (4)
```

- E.g., for a negative 4-bit (2's complement) number,

```
1010 (-6)
1100 (-4) &
-------
1000 (-8)
```

`%` is the modulo operator. `x % y` roughly means `x - parseInt(x / y) * x`

- E.g., for a positive number, `8 % 3 === 2`
- E.g., for a negative number, `-8 % 3 === -2`

### Now to answer the question

For our explanation, let's simply and use `i & 0b0011 (3)` and `1 % 0b0100 (4)` instead of 255 and 256. This is equivalent for the purposes of this question, since `256` in binary is `10000...` and `0xff` in binary is `01111...`.

- For positives numbers less than 4: both `i & 0b0011` and `1 % 0b0100` will  return `i`.

`2 % 4 = 4`

```
0010 (2)
0011 (3) &
-------
0010 (2)
```

- For positives numbers greater than or equal to 4: both `i & 0b0011` and `1 % 0b0100`,

`7 % 4 = 3`

```
0111 (7)
0011 (3) &
-------
0011 (3)
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because these operations are different, so you don't ask why `2+2` equals to `2*2`, but `2+3` != `2*3`, right?

anyway, the main problem is that bitwise representation of number is not 1:1 relation, different numbers can have the same representation (check [Signed versus Unsigned Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247873/signed-versus-unsigned-integers##targetText=Unsigned%20can%20hold%20a%20larger,both%20positive%20and%20negative%20numbers). for some details)

so, `%` modulo operator takes remainder of division and it has sign, so

```js
console.log(-100 % 256); // shows -100 which is true
```

bitwise `&` works with physical bits, it has no understanding of sign bit set so, if we look at bitwise representation of -100 - it is `10011100` and at the same time it is bitwise representation for 156

```js
console.log((0b10011100)); // unsigned 156
console.log((0b10011100 << 24 >> 24)); // signed -100
```