# set int type length in phpmyadmin unlimited

Tags: mysql

I have a brief question. When creating my database in phpmyadmin, I have a table name of all_points. The type is INT. How do I set the value or length to unlimited so it can be however long I wish it to be? Is that not what length/values does?
Any help would be appreciated with kindness. (Just starting out in PHP)

Comment: If you're talking about the number in brackets, ie `INT(4)`, that's just the [display width](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html). MySQL's integer data types all have fixed ranges but some can support very large numbers. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: so the max is 4294967295

Comment: For an unsigned `INT`, yes. If you need larger numbers, use `BIGINT`

Comment: thanks! but what does unassigned mean

Comment: But when I put 4294967295 it says display width out of range - max 255

Comment: _**Unsigned**_, not _unassigned_. See [Signed versus Unsigned Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247873/signed-versus-unsigned-integers)

Comment: so if I leave it blank?

Comment: Just to be clear, leaving it blank gives it a value of 4294967295

Comment: I suggest you read all the links I've provided, particularly [this one](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) and the duplicate question link

Comment: Ok thanks for your time!